# Bigcommerce API status code 401

Tags: ajax, api, bigcommerce

I got the error

```
Failed to load https://store-cmr1f5oakh.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://tim-yma5.mybigcommerce.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

---

I used ajax to call the api

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://url/api/v2/products",
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username" + ":" + "token"));
        },
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log("api_success");
        }
    });
```

How can i avoid `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` ?

Answer (score 0):

try to modify the data type to `jsonp`

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://url/api/v2/products",
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username" + ":" + "token"));
        },
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            console.log("api_success");
        }
    });
```

you can use also in your HTML :

```
 <head>...<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">...</head>
```

but you'd better configure your webserver or webapp to send this header

Comment: Hi Azzabi. I appreciate your help. However, it did not work. It just returned a popup asking for username and passowrd. even when I inserted the meta

Comment: var strURL = "/api/v2/products.json";
        
  
        var auth = demo()
   
    //alert(auth)
  $.ajax({
   url: strURL,
      method: 'GET',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {sku:productCode},
   crossDomain: true,
   beforeSend : function(req) 
   { 
    req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
   },

Comment: I have using in our free demo store using custom page inside javascript apply this code and always getting request error unauthorized issue facing